# Having trouble initialising an array of a custom class

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Here's the code:

```
public class RhombMap
{
    private Vector3 size;
    private Rhomb[][][] map;

    public RhombMap( int sizeX, int sizeY, int sizeZ )
    {
        size = new Vector3 (sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ);
        Rhomb[][][] map = new Rhomb[sizeX] [sizeY] [sizeZ];
    }
}
```

Which is annoyingly giving me the error:

```
Assets/Scripts/MapController.cs(186,46): error CS0021: Cannot apply indexing 
with [] to an expression of type `Rhomb'
```

I'm not trying to index it, I'm trying to initialise an array *of* it, using exactly the same syntax as in [Microsoft's own tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453(v=vs.71).aspx).

Can anyone spot what is, hopefully, a glaring error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a difference between **3d** array which you can initialize in one go:

```
  Rhomb[,,] map = new Rhomb[sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ];
```

and **jagged** array (array of array of array) where you have to create each of the inner arrays:

```
  Rhomb[][][] map = Enumerable
    .Range(0, SizeX)
    .Select(x => Enumerable
       .Range(0, SizeY)
       .Select(y => new Rhomb[SizeZ])
       .ToArray())
    .ToArray();
```

Please, notice, that you've *redeclared* `map` as a *local variable* within `RhombMap` constructor

**Edit:** diffrence between *2d* array (let me not put *3d*) and *jagged* one illustrated:

```
// 2d: always rectangle (2x3 in this case - 2 rows each of 3 items)
// that's why when been initializing wants just width and height
int[,] arr2d = new int[,] 
  {{1, 2, 3}
   {4, 5, 6}};

// width and hight
int[,] arr2d_empty = new int[2, 3]; 

// jagged: all rows (subarrays) are of arbitrary lengths
// that's why when been initializing wants all rows been initialized individually 
int[][] jagged = new int[][] {
  new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4}, // 4 items
  new int[] {5},          // 1 item
  new int[] {6, 7, 8},    // 3 items
};

// each line (subarray) must be specified
int[][] jagged_empty = new int[][] {
  new int[4],
  new int[1],
  new int[3], 
};
```

Comment: Ah, so I need to initialise each sub-array in turn? I need to use jagged arrays, you see, as they aren't all going to be the same length.

Comment: @Tim no, that is not what jagged means. Jagged means the number of elements change between rows. If you are trying to represent a cube like shape a 3d array is the better one.

Comment: @Scott sorry, I wasn't very clear with what I was saying, the arrays are indeed all going to be different lengths, which is why I do need to use jagged ones. Thanks for the clarification though!

Comment: @TimLeach I really think you don't understand what I am saying. From your example code all your rows are the same length in each axis. That is when you use a 3d array. `map = new Romb[sizeX, sizeY, sizeZ];`

Comment: @Scott I do understand that, I'm going to be changing the code later such that everything is variable, I was simply trying to start with the simplest case. I will need to have different sizes when I implement different "shapes" for this map object, as I'm doing something like [this](http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/#map-storage), but in 3D.

Answer (score -1):

```
private Rhomb[][][] map;
...
Rhomb[][][] map = ...
```

You've declared a new variable with the same name.

Additionally, as you've declared an array-of-arrays, you can't one-line create a new instance.  You can either use one of Dmitry's solutions or do it this way:

```
map = new Rhomb[sizeX][][];
for(int x = 0; x < sizeX; x++) {
    map[x] = new Rhomb[sizeY][];
    for(int y = 0; y < sizeY; y++) {
        map[x][y] = new Rhomb[sizeZ];
    }
}
```

I still think Dmitry's solution of declaring your array as `Rhomb[,,]` would be best, though.

Comment: Thanks! Problem is, this still returns exactly the same error :(

Comment: @TimLeach Sorry about that, I didn't even catch the jagged-array/3D array that Dmitry's answer picked up on. I have edited my answer